# ng-draggable with two ng-drag-clone on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I am using the library [ng-draggable](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable).I have two draggle list and two cloned divs on one page and I want each list to have their own ng-drag-clone but both point to the same cloned div.

Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PJ5GLg6ZLRiqvtkLactL?p=previeww

```
<div ng-drag-clone="dependencies" class="droppable-list" style="background-color: red">
    {{vm.clonedData.name}}
</div>
<div ng-drag-clone="selections" class="droppable-list" style="background-color: yellow">
    {{vm.clonedData.name}}
</div>
```